# Getting Annotated Spring bean in jsp

Tags: spring, annotations, jsp-tags

I have problem in getting Spring bean from JSP. I have a Spring bean configured using annotation:

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultServiceConfiguration extends AbstractSpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ExService exService() {
        ExServiceImpl service = new ExServiceImpl();
        return service;
    }
}
```

And the `ExServiceImpl` is as below:

```
public ExServiceImpl implements ExService {
    @Override
    public String getApprove(Integer x) {
        // .....
        return approve;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to acccess the Beans method in JSP:

```
<c:set var="clientApprove" scope="request" value="${ExService .getApprove(1)}"/>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: You don't want that. Don't access beans from your view. Use proper MVC for that, learn things the correct way.

Comment: That bean exists in the Spring context, not searchable in your page context. By the way consider what @M.Deinum said.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum , yes I understand that. But, I don't have access for the controller to add changes there. Either I need to override the Controller and make the changes, which will be difficult since the controller class is in library. I appreciate if there is any way to access it in jsp..

Comment: You can but as stated you shouldn't as that is a really bad idea. Either create a new controller to do this. If you can change the page you can also change the controller, what use is a changed page if the controller cannot handle the new things.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not good design at all, and you shall avoid it.

But I believe this will help you:

```
@Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.REQUEST, name="myBean")
public ExService exService() {
    ExServiceImpl service = new ExServiceImpl();
    return service;
}
```

But then the bean will not be singleton.

Answer (score -1):

I think we should add @Service annotation above the ExServiceImpl class to create the bean Service

```
@Service
public ExServiceImpl implements ExService {
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant. He is using `JavaConfig`, so the `@Service` is not needed.